# Can someone please list down the side quest on LoL

Tags: league-of-legends

I just started wondering, what are the side quest in all maps and what are the requirements?

I know about the "The Hunt is On" quest. Hope you can add some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 2 sidequests or "events" as they are called officially. These events can only occur in normal and custom games, since they have a too big impact on ranked.

The first one is as you said "[The Hunt is On!](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hunt_is_On!)" (Rengar + Kha'Zix)
The second one is "[The battle for Freljord](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_for_Freljord)" (Ashe, Lissandra, Sejuani)

There are however some sidequests in the battle tutorial. These include mostly objectives and jungling.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the previous poster said, there is still one other sidequest that I know of. I forgot the exact name of the quest, but it revolves around Jinx, Vi, and Caitlyn. Whenever Jinx kills a Vi or Caitlyn, it adds up to his "Officers Jinxed" counter. Every count gives her bonuses iirc, but it's a very small one so it is neglectable. The opposite goes with Vi and Caitlyn, wherein a counter is added whenever you kill a Jinx. This whole side quest is a nod to their lores, in which Jinx is a criminal In Piltover, and Caitlyn and Vi are the police officers there. There are more of this easter-ish eggs in LoL. These things are what makes the game cool to me.

Comment: This is actually a hidden passive not an event. It's called [Catch me if you can](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Easter_eggs/Hidden_Passive#Catch_me_if_you_can.21) and has no direct impact to the game itself.

Comment: also another hidden passives are zealan(i forgot his actual name!) and vollibear. the ninja tribes, akali and/or shen and/or kennen wherein they have -1 hp when in the same team called `inverse ninja strength`. also a `plant vs zombie` like scenario where the zombie characters(i.e sion) will have an effect to zyra.