# What is the point of Rengar vs Kha'zix anymore?

Tags: league-of-legends

There is a mini-quest in LoL that when there's a Kha'zix and Rengar on opposite teams, a duel between them is initiated somewhere along in the game. The question is, what's the point of it anymore if Rengar doesn't lose stacks anymore even if he dies.

Comment: related or duplicate : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/154804/61395  Unless Riot changed how "The hunt is on" ends (changing item or Rengar or buff to Khaz), it's still adds a little something.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau maybe a (very)little relevance but not a duplicate, i think?

Comment: I'm more inclined over duplicate since you ask what is the point of the quest while that point hasn't changed. It's still the same quest.

Comment: That's like saying it's pointless to have the ninja secret if all ninjas got buffed by one base HP. It's just something there to add some fun for those who notice or know of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point to it doesnt change, its still the same as before - Just a little extra fun and lore interaction.
The only difference is that with rengar not being able to lose stacks, The Hunt is more likely to happen now.

The Hunt occurs when Rengar has atleast 10 stacks, and Khazix has used 3 evolution points.

Whoever kills the other first gains an additional bonus.
Rengar gains "The Head of Khazix", which is a fully stacked necklace. You can skip from 10 to 20 stacks if thats how many stacks he has.

As of patch 4.14 Rengar also gains additional vision in brushes with the head of Khazix.
(Thanks [Caffeinated Cake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179917/what-is-the-point-of-rengar-vs-khazix-anymore/179920#comment244594_179920))

Khazix gains an additional evolution point if he wins.

Comment: Moreover, as stated in the patch note 4.14: "Rengar now has increased vision range while in a brush with the Head of Kha'Zix" [(link patch note)](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-414-notes)